# Is it worth doing Whimsyshire in Hell to get upgrades for Inferno

Tags: diablo-iii

So I'm wondering what is more efficient to farm gear for inferno. Once I acquired the ability to open the 'cow level' do the item drops and gold drops justify the effort to get the staff in the first place? Are there champions/rare mobs in Whimsyshire that increase my Nephalem Valor buff?
Or am I better off just running Act I-IV hell and partially Act I inferno and hope for good items/gold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed rare and champion mobs in Whimsyshire with plenty of chests to loot. I have ran the level a few times on hell and the loot is what you would expect. The loot is equivalent to that of act 3 or 4. The pro to Inferno is that it has the ability to drop better, higher end gear. If you can farm Inferno (at least the skeleton king) at a regular rate I would suggest that you do that. If Inferno is giving you a hard time, Whimsyshire is as good as any other place in Hell to farm.